# Excel : How Can I Get First Cell Content

Tags: excel, ms-office

How Can I Get First Cell Content ?
here is my sheet

```
    A  
1  Color

2  Red

3  Blue

4  Yellow
```

note : Color has filter

i want to make the cell B1 = first cell of column A - I try type in B1 =A2

but when i make filter (example i select blue) the cell B2 show nothing (i want B1 to show the filtered data on first column )

Comment: do you open for user defined functions (VBA)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **B1** enter the array formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:A100,MATCH(1,SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2:A100,ROW(A2:A100)-ROW($A$2),,1)),0))
```

Array formula must be entered with **CNTRL-SHFT-ENTER** rather than just the **ENTER** key

Answer (score 1):

A Non-Volatile AND Non-Array entered option is to use a helper column:

In `B2` Enter `=SUBTOTAL(3,A2)` and drag it down. This will mark every row with a 0 or a 1 depending on if it is visible or not.

Then in B1 you can simply enter:

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(1,B2:B4,0))
```

The above will search the `B` column for the first 1 (stands for visible), and return the value of the cell in column A of that row.